# How do I install Genymotion on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: emulation, genymotion

How do I install Genymotion on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 4):

According to [PKGBUILD from ArchLinux AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=genymotion) - you have to

install VirtualBox

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

then download the GenyMotion and install it with

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://dl.genymotion.com/releases/genymotion-3.1.0/genymotion-3.1.0-linux_x64.bin
yes | sudo bash ./genymotion-3.1.0-linux_x64.bin -d /usr/local/
```

then optionally create symlinks for binaries with:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/genymotion/genymotion /usr/local/bin/genymotion
sudo ln -s /usr/local/genymotion/genymotion-shell /usr/local/bin/genymotion-shell
sudo ln -s /usr/local/genymotion/player /usr/local/bin/genymotion-player
sudo ln -s /usr/local/genymotion/gmtool /usr/local/bin/gmtool
```

It seems that you need to obtain license to get it working.
Possible free alternative may be [Anbox](https://anbox.io/) (installed from Snap with `snap install anbox`).

Comment: If you have secure boot enabled you will have trouble configuring virtual box. Follow these steps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248315/sign-virtual-box-modules-vboxdrv-vboxnetflt-vboxnetadp-vboxpci-centos-8